# Mixture and alligation problem based on ratio type

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> An alloy contains brass,iron and Zinc in the ratio 2:3:1 and another
>   contains iron,zinc,lead in the ratio 5:4:3,If equal weights of both
>   alloys are melted together to form a 3 alloy. what will be the weight
>   of lead perkg in new alloy?

**I am unable to proceed this sum because two alloys contains brass and lead are different alloys,How to approach this sum and how to find the answer please guide me anyone**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first alloy you don't have any lead. In one kg of the third alloy you have 0.5 kg of the first alloy and 0.5 kg of the second alloy. That means that you need to calculate how much lead you have in 0.5 kg of the second alloy. The second alloy is made out of 12 parts (5+4+3), and only three parts out of that is lead

Comment: please explain in detail,I am not able to get you @Andrei

Comment: Which part do you have problem with?

Comment: Totally what you are telling i am not getting @Andrei, can you please explain the answer in step by step

Comment: Start from the end. You have 1 kg of alloy number 3. How much alloy number 1, and how much alloy number 2 did you use?

Comment: 0.5 kg of alloy1 and 0.5 kg alloy2 @Andrei,but they did not mention 1 kg of alloy number3

Comment: Now how much lead you have in the first alloy? Also, explain the meaning of "5:4:3" in your problem

Comment: In first alloy there is no lead but for second alloy it contains 3/12 @Andrei

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55590/discussion-between-andrei-and-learning-user).